# Image won't appear in Xcode

Tags: xcode, uiimage, imageview

I'm a first time programmer and i'm trying to make a soundboard app. Its not finished yet and it is pretty basic. I have a main menu with one button. When this button is pressed, a different background image should appear along with a back button. The image does not change. here is the code:

```
-(IBAction)redgradient {

    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"redgradient.jpg"];
    [imageView setImage:img];

}

-(IBAction)redgradient2 {

    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"redgradient2.png"];
    [imageView setImage:img];

}
```

I have mentioned the IBActions in the H file and used an IBOutlet of ImageView. Help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you add the image files to your project?

Comment: Yes I have the corresponding images in the project

Comment: Problem could be that one of your files is a JPEG and not a PNG. PNG is the preferred format, although JPEGs should work. Can you make a PNG version of that file and try it? Don't forget to change the file name on disk and in the code (and add the new file to your project). Worth a try, anyway.

Comment: It worked! Thanks for the help. Now I have another problem- The image is infront of the button so you cant see it. How can i dictate the order? I also have a UIControl. While the UIImageView is active, i cannot use this control. How can i use the UIControl whilst using the UIImageView?

Comment: If you are using Interface builder, the order of UI elements, from "back" to "front" is represented by the list of those elements from top to bottom when viewing the contents of the xib file in "list" view. (Does that make sense?) Make sure your UIImageView is shown first, which means it will be behind everything else.

Comment: Thanks, i got it to work. One last question please, how do i make a UIControl disappear once a button is pressed? do i simply do a press IBAction and write something like control.hidden = 0 etc.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a more simple way to do that, test if this works better:

```
-(IBAction)redgradient {

    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"redgradient.jpg"];

}

-(IBAction)redgradient2 {

    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"redgradient2.png"];

}
```

Check if the images ends on .jpg or .png if that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things to check:

1. The image files have been added to the project.
2. The image names are **exactly** as they appear in the project (case sensitive and correct format).
3. The connections are properly established in the IB.

Comment: @Ryan, you can try tossing in `[imageView setNeedsDisplay];`, but otherwise your code is fine and if these items are all correct, then I'm stumped.